# Render Freestyle strokes behind objects with alpha transparency?

Tags: freestyle, transparency

I'm trying to make a wall disappear. Does freestyle support alpha? I mean there is an alpha for strokes but all it does is making my lines disappear but I still can't see strokes behind the wall

[image: FreeStyleTest2]

And here is the blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29200

Comment: thx for the edit, it is more obvious now ;)

Comment: I have just got a result with layering and compositing, I'm making 1 layer to slowly disappear and 2nd to draw the final picture with insides. Then blending them with alphaover. For my particular problem it works but I'm still wondering if there is any better way.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can do this easily from the Freestyle settings. Blender/Freestyle gives you a lot of control. The parameter you want to change is QI Range. This specifies a range of face occlusion to render strokes for. So if you have a cube like in the example below you would set the range Start at 1, and End at 1 or higher and that would render strokes for the edges of the back of the cube.

[image: Blender Freestyle QI Range]

However if you had a second cube behind your first one, a range of Start:1~End:1 will cause the second cube not to have strokes rendered in the areas which are occluded by the foreground cube. Here is an example:

[image: Freestyle QI Range Start1 End1]

And if we up the values to Start:2~End:2 the foreground cube's back edges are not rendered but the front edges of the background cube are:

[image: Freestyle QI Range Start2 End2]

Here is your scene rendered with values of Start:1~End:100 and Alpha set to 0.5 for the occluded stroke set:

[image: Your example scene with QI Range and Alpha]

Here is the .blend: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31648

And finally, here is the section of the Blender manual which explains this if you want to read further: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_set.html

Comment: Yeah, Mentalist, I have no clue where to find any of those settings.

Comment: Everything I think "this won't be possible in Blender" I'm proven wrong. Amazing answer, thank you, helped me so much.

Comment: @Owen I'm glad I could help! Yeah, Blender is amazing. Let's keep growing and supporting the community to keep it amazing.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

QI Is indeed the answer but the featured response doesn't tell you where it is: I found it in

**Blender Properties Tab\View Layer Properties\Freestyle\Visibility:**

Set Visible to Quantitative Invisibility, and only then can you adjust the depth.