# How to render as only wireframe in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, wireframe

I need to know how to render a object on Blender Cycles but only as a wireframe, for example, like this:

[image]

Also, it is possible to vary between the smooth wireframe object and the polygonal wireframe object?

Thanks in regard.

Comment: You can do this using OpenGL render and by pressing `Z` > Wireframe int he viewport

Comment: You could use freestyle.

Comment: How? this is my first time trying to render like this, also i need this for an animation, not an static render.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/how-to-render-an-object-as-a-transparent-wireframe/14939#14939

Comment: Dear God! That looks like the Animus's loading screed from Assassin's Creed. Good job man,I like it and I hope you continue on this project.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the ***Wireframe modifier*** and adjust the *Thickness* value.
[image]
[image]

Now set up the *World*'s color to black and make the wire look brighter (replace Diffuse with an Emission shader). You may also increase its *Strenght* value to 2.000 or 3.000 if it isn't bright enough.
[image]
[image]

To vary between the smooth wireframe object and the polygonal wireframe object place the *Subdivision Surface modifier* above the *Wireframe modifier* and set up the desired amount of subdivisions. Now changing the type from *Catmull-Clark* to *Simple* will result in making the wire look more polygonal.
[image]

Here's the rendered result.
[image]

Comment: If like me you don't see the wireframe modifier in the "generate" column, perhaps it's because you need to scroll down the list, as the panel is too short for this column in version 3.1.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Paul Gonet's answer, we now have the wireframe node in cycles (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>>*Input*>*Wireframe*).

[image]

Using the pixel size checkbox, you can make the width of the wireframe remain constant no matter the camera position.

Comment: Just in case somebody else bumps into this: make sure the transparent shader goes into the *second* channel of the Mix Shader, and the Diffuse (or otherwise) material goes into the *third*. If you switch these two around, the effect won't work. it took me 15 minutes to find out. :) But maybe this is obvious for experienced Blender users.