# How To Render a Wireframe of a model in Blender 2.8

Tags: freestyle, wireframe

I’m trying to render the wireframes of a model for a turntable animation in Blender 2.8 to show in my portfolio. The turntable renders the mesh perfectly, but the Freestyle Line Set renders only the wireframe of the first rendered frame. Is this a bug or do I miss some settings? I attached a blend file for reference.

For the wireframe I use the Freestyle option, I marked all the edges with Ctrl+E -> Mark Freestyle Edge and uses the following settings on the View Layer tab

[image]

This is what happened when I render a turntable. I use Blender 2.80 Beta (Date: 2019-01-07 23:37)
[image]

[image]

Comment: FWIW works as expected for me, (ubuntu 64 bit) built yesterday from source.

Comment: See if this helps, maybe?
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23616/how-to-render-as-only-wireframe-in-cycles