# Freestyle lines behind transparent plane blender 3d

Tags: transparency, freestyle

Please, help me. I have a problem with Freestyle (eevee/cycles)
I want to draw cube lines behind with transparency.
I have already experimented with groups and collections (already in the past).
Post image processing from two renders will also not work. I need animation with a tree in the foreground.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try looking here - I played around for a minute, but couldn't find the correct combo to show the outlines properly, but I definitely was able to show lines behind the transparency. Maybe you'll have more luck than me - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/render-freestyle-strokes-behind-objects-with-alpha-transparency

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dHiTnHc9IvYU8XgC44vkbdl1GlQB-4K_)  Thanks. Now my problem has increased :)

Comment: my file is in the folder by link

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the compositor.

Go to Render Properties > Film and check the box Transparent.
Then go to Render Properties and check the box Freestyle. (but *don't* have any linesets in Freestyle Line Set under View Layer Properties)

Put the plane with an image using alpha in a collection.
Put the object that will have freestyle lines in another collection.

Disable the freestyle-object-collection by unchecking the box next to it in the Outliner. (keep the collection with the image checked/enabled)

[image]

Make a second viewlayer by clicking the Add View Layer icon. (usually in the top right of the screen).

In this viewlayer check the box next to the freestyle-object-collection, but uncheck the box next to the plane-with-image-collection.

Also in this viewlayer we *do* want a freestyle lineset: View Layer Properties > Freestyle Line Set, and click the plus icon to add one.

In the Compositor window, create two Render Layers nodes. Set one to the first viewlayer (with the plane-with-image-collection enabled), and the other to the second viewlayer (with the freestyle-object-collection enabled and with the freestyle lineset), and plug them in an Alpha Over node. Plug the Alpha Over node in a Viewer node.

Render and then select the Viewer node in the Image Editor.

[image]

Comment: This is a band-aid solution, especially for cycles renders. Is there a way to do this so that light rays can still interact with both objects?

Comment: Does nothing for self-overlapping transparent geometry, ie, on one same object, transparent faces on top of other transparent faces causing the behind edges not to be freestyled.